# print OO expression tree in java

Tags: java, recursion, tree, expression

I'm working on a java object oriented expression tree assignment where I need to be able to eval and print expression trees in prefix/infix/postfix formats. The assignment describes a class hierarchy with static type "Exp" and several unary and binary subclasses.

I've solved the eval part by having the unary and binary classes implement the eval() method (as dictated by the root type "Exp"), but need help with printing the expression. I've worked with this for days now and have gotten nowhere. All the help I've found online is about binary classes that has both operator and values fields (my assignment has these as two different classes). Please give me a kick in the right direction - I'll be most grateful :-)

Best wishes,
Rasmus

```
public interface Exp { double value(); }
public class Value implements Exp {
    private double value;    
    public Value(double val)    { this.value = val; }    
    public double value()       { return this.value; }
}
public class Binary implements Exp {
    private char op; private Exp right; private Exp left;

    public Binary(char op, Exp left, Exp right) { 
        this.op = op; this.left = left; this.right = right; 
    }
}
    public double value() { // sum up using recursion
        switch(this.op) {
            case '+':   return this.left.value()+this.right.value();
            case '-':   return this.left.value()-this.right.value();
            case '*':   return this.left.value()*this.right.value();
            case '/':   return this.left.value()/this.right.value();
            default:    return Double.NaN;
        }
    }   
}
public class Main { //calculating total ok - needs printing!
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Exp valLeft = new Value(10);
        Exp valRight = new Value(5);
        Exp bN1 = new Binary('+', valLeft, valRight);
        Exp bN2 = new Binary('+', bN1, new Value(3));
        System.out.println(bN2.value());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do the infix. The prefix and postfix should be possible for you once you see how this one is done.

In the `Exp` interface, add:

```
String asInfix();
```

In the `Binary` class, add:

```
public final String asInfix() {
  return "(" + left.asInfix() + " " + op + " " + right.asInfix() + ")";
}
```

In the `Value` class, add:

```
public final String asInfix() {
  return "" + value;
}
```

Now you can do `System.out.println(bN2.asInfix());` to display `((10.0 + 5.0) + 3.0)`.

Comment: Fantastic(!) :-) may I ask why you declare the method final?

Comment: It's just a habit, since I don't usually do any subclassing.  Feel free to omit it.

Answer (score 0):

Approach it in same manner. Override `toString` so that it calls it recursively for `left` and `right` in case of `Binary`, and returns the value for `Value` nodes.

Comment: Dear Xion, I've extended my static type with a print method, and implemented this along with overridden toString. When printing the expression I create in the test the recursion appears to go only one level?